# Qt - C++ Graphical application in visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt

I want to create graphical application (drawing and moving squares and so) using C++. I was suggested to use [Qt library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_%28software%29) for this. I am windows user and I use Visual Studio 2013 for developing C++ (console) apps. So I typed Qt download into google hoping to find some package of DLLs, libs, headers or something like that so I could include headers and link libraries with my code. But all I found was IDE Qt Creator (which I do not want) and Qt Visual Studio plugin (which I downloaded, but it still requires whole IDE to work). So my question is - How can I develop graphical application (no forms, just "canvas" to draw on with some mouse/keyboard support) using Qt library, C++ language and Visual Studio IDE, without requirement of downloading tons of GBs for IDE or plugins I do not want, with insurance that application would be easily deployable on most common operating systems.

The reason I do not want Qt creator IDE is simple -- There is a chance for this to be semester project and will be reviewed by teacher without any extra IDEs. (I'll send him just VS project/generated Makefile and Qt libraries with headers)

Thanks for clarification.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious: please... read the qt tagwiki. `QT` is an entirely different project. Either way, the question is not on topic for this site, but I do not have close votes left for today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is: you cannot. You need `Qt SDK`, which comes with `Qt Creator`.

`Qt` comes with `qmake` build system and it does not require any IDE to compile and run the application. You can write in any IDE you want and compile anywhere, where `Qt SDK` and compiler is available.

If you want to provide the application to your teacher, he must have `Qt SDK` too to compile it. There is no way around this. And better test the application in the target environment. Writing portable applications is not a trivial task - if you hardcode paths like `C:\QtSDK\path\to\something`, there is little chance to run it under `Linux` without any changes.

If you cannot expect any SDK on a teacher's computer, you have few options:

1. convince her to install necessary tools
2. ask her what tools are permitted and stick with them
3. bring your own computer for final evaluation